# How to make OSM player PLAY and PAUSE?

Tags: media-player

I have been trying to build some custom video player functionality against OSM Player:

http://mediafront.org/osmplayer/

I have SCOURED their website and googled all over the place but I cannot find how to programmatically (via javascript) play and pause the video. All their examples show how to auto-play video on page load and that works fine. But I need to programmatically pause and play according to my custom events. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the OSM creator and he told me how to do this. In case it helps others:

```
function play(){
    minplayer.get('media', function(media) {
      media.play();
    });
  }

  function pause(){
    minplayer.get('media', function(media) {
      media.pause();
    });
  }

  function skip(skipSeconds){
    minplayer.get('media', function(media) {
      media.seek(skipSeconds);
    });
  }
```